# Bitcoin - Creating address with pywallet.py, how secure is it?

Tags: bitcoin

I'm using pywallet.py --info --importhex --importprivkey PASSWORD to create my own Bitcoin addresses. I'm thinking of using a long password HJNKND/678J***?¡\bhkbfNCHgv&%$bvd_ and add a counter for each new address.

For example:
Address 1: HJNKND/678J***?¡\bhkbfNCHgv&%$bvd_1
Address 2: HJNKND/678J***?¡\bhkbfNCHgv&%$bvd_2
etc

Is this secure? Or does it have and obvious flaw I'm not aware?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

pywallet.py is secure enough, but basic security steps is also required of course. Depending on Linux distribution you're using if your machine is desktop/connected to network then nobody can guarantee that there's no trojans.

Most experts recommend having isolated machine not connected to the Internet to generate wallets & other activities like that